# Hibernate OneToMany/ManyToOne List Return

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

These are my tables below and very few records are in them.

```
                                    EMPLOYEE TABLE
______________________________________________________________________________________
|  id  |  username  |  name  |  surname  |     mail    |password|salary|deptId| type |
|------|------------|--------|-----------|-------------|--------|------|------|------|
|  1   |    jdoe    |  John  |    Doe    | jdoe@doe.com|  123   |  31  |  15  |annon |
|  2   |    wise    | Wise   | Sunshine  | ws@ws@com   |  345   |  62  |  15  |visib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DEPARTMENT TABLE
_________________
|  id  |  name  |
|------|--------|
|  15  |Backend |
|  16  |Fontend |
|  17  |Unknown |
-----------------
```

My `Employee` class below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column
private String username;
@Column
private String name;
@Column
private String surname;
@Column
private String mail;
@Column
private String password;
@Column
private String salary;

@Column
private String type;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
private Department deptId;

//setters getters
//constructors
```

}

My `Department` class is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH }, mappedBy = "deptId")
private List<Employee> employes;

public void add(final Employee employee) {

    if (this.employes == null) {
        this.employes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    this.employes.add(employee);
    employee.setDeptId(this);
}

//setter getters
//constructors
```

}

`DepartmentDao` omplementation:

```
public class DepartmentDaoImpl implements DepartmentDao {
Session session;

@Override
public void addDepartment(final Department dept) {
    this.session.persist(dept);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public List<Department> listDepartments() {
    return this.session.createCriteria(Department.class).list();
}

@Override
public Department getDepartmentById(final int id) {
    return this.session.get(Department.class, id);
}

@Override
public void deleteDepartment(final int id) {
    this.session.delete(id);

}

public Session getSession() {
    return this.session;
}

public void setSession(final Session session) {
    this.session = session;
}
```

}

`EmployeeDao` Implementation:

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    Session session;

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(final Employee employee) {
        this.session.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Employee> listEmployees() {
        return this.session.createCriteria(Employee.class).list();
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(final int id) {
        return this.session.get(Employee.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEmployee(final int id) {
        this.session.delete(this.session.get(Employee.class, id));
    }

    public void updateEmployee(final Employee employee) {
        this.session.update(employee);
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return this.session;
    }

    public void setSession(final Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

I do call `listDepartments` from `ManagementServiceClass` as below:

```
public List<Department> getDepartmentList() {
    List<Department> departmentList;
    try {
        this.session = Service.FACTORY.openSession();
        this.departmentDao.setSession(this.session);
        this.session.beginTransaction();
        departmentList = this.departmentDao.listDepartments();
        this.session.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        this.session.close();
    }
    return departmentList;
}
```

The problem is that, when I only want list of departments from the department table, I use the `listDepartments()` in `DepartmentDaoImpl`, but that returns

```
Department[15,Backend]  
Department[15,Backend]
Department[15,Backend]
Department[16,Frontend]
Department[17,UNKNOWN]
```

instead of just those 3 departments. So I suppose the amount of `Employee`s that belong in particular departments are returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's really odd behavior, your code should not be able to produce a list larger than the actual listing in the table. Can you post more of your code, like where you call `listDepartments()`?

Comment: @Yserbius Ive added where I do call it from. There is ManagamentService class calling it. ManagamentService is called to fill the list basically. like List<Department> deptList = managamentService.getDepartmentList(); When I debug it, in the dao, departmentList contains the records that I gave in the question which I have no idea why. I was thinking maybe I am doing something wrong with the mapping OneToMany or ManyToOne since I am really newbie in hibernate.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This is quite hard to read as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `EmployeeDao` we have to implement

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Employee> listEmployees() {
    return this.session.createCriteria(Employee.class).
    setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
}
```

Comment: You mean in DepartmentDao or EmployeeDao? I am confused because there is not listEmployees() method in DepartmentDao. If so may I ask why? What does that mean?

Comment: sorry, it's EmployeeDao Implementation change it. your operation will work